# How to set heights of columns equal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am using Gentelella bootstrap template and I have a problem with the height of one of my panels.

The problem is that the left `x_panel` has smaller height than the right one. The different between these panels is that the left one contains `svg` element, while the right one contains `canvas` with `chart.js`. How can I set the heights equal?

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Title of the chart<small>Sub-title</small></h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="x_content">
            <svg class="company"></svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Title of the chart <small>Sub-title</small></h2>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="x_content">
            <canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: use `flex` for it

Comment: @LKG: Could you please give an example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t05d39vf/1/

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the SVG to the same as the height of your Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.row>div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h2>Title of the chart<small>Sub-title</small></h2>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">
        <svg class="company"></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h2>Title of the chart <small>Sub-title</small></h2>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">
        <canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code. Take a look at my update where I posted the screenshot of the page after running your code. Indeed the elements `x_panel` are not equally sized, as you may see.

Comment: Yeah, but that's related to the content of the panel. What's the CSS for x_panel? Setting width: 100% for the SVG may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[fiddle link with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/t05d39vf/3/)**

You also use

```
.child {
  width:50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
   /*width:50%;*/   /* You can use width instead of flex */
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea temporibus officia vel, placeat quisquam ipsum a perspiciatis ex sit nobis adipisci ab ipsam vitae esse fugit accusamus eum iure provident.
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi tempore nihil
  </div>
</div>
```

With Bootstrap and your code.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
          <h2>Title of the chart<small>Sub-title</small></h2>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
          <svg class="company"></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
          <h2>Title of the chart <small>Sub-title</small></h2>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="x_content">
          <canvas id="mybarChart"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So, in my case `div class="row box">` and `<div class="x_panel child">`. Right? I tested it, but then both charts have a very small height (it's impossible to see graphics) and the background is light blue (don't know why).

Comment: not nesting you like `<div class=row`><div class=child like that

Comment: I think your graph is not taking their height  if content is there it will work fine please check graph's js.